# Fill new pandas df column based off values in another

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause, fill

I am trying to create a new `column` in a `pandas df` that is filled by values in another `column`. Specifically, for the df below I want to fill `1` next to the `'Home'` values in `Col['Location']`.

```
import pandas as pd

d = ({
    'Day' : ['Mon','Tues','Mon','Wed','Thurs','Fri','Mon','Sat','Sun','Tues'],                 
    'Location' : ['Home','Home','Away','Home','Home','Home','Home','Home','Home','Away'],               
     })

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I am currently doing it via this:

```
m = lambda x: dict(Home='1').get(x, '')
df = df.assign(Assign=df.Location.map(m))
```

However, I want to include `Col['Day']` to alter the new column values. I'm hoping to `assign` numbers in three allotments. For the 1st three unique values in `Day`, I want to label them all `1`. For the 4th, 5th, 6th unique values I want to label them `2` etc.

So for `Location` value of `Home` df, The first 3 `unique` values in `Day` are `Mon, Tues, Wed` so they would all have 1 next to them. The 4th, 5th, 6th unique values are  `Thurs, Fri, Sat` so they would have `2` next to them. `Sun` is over `6` so it would have a `3`

Intended Output:

```
     Day Location Assign
0    Mon     Home      1
1   Tues     Home      1
2    Mon     Away       
3    Wed     Home      1
4  Thurs     Home      2
5    Fri     Home      2
6    Mon     Home      1
7    Sat     Home      2
8    Sun     Home      3
9   Tues     Away
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think first filter only `Home` rows, remove duplicates and create dictionary for [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) - but only for filtered rows:

```
mask = df['Location'] == 'Home'
df1 = df[mask].drop_duplicates('Day')
d = dict(zip(df1['Day'], np.arange(len(df1)) // 3 + 1))

df.loc[mask, 'Assign'] = df.loc[mask, 'Day'].map(d)
print (df)
     Day Location  Assign
0    Mon     Home     1.0
1   Tues     Home     1.0
2    Mon     Away     NaN
3    Wed     Home     1.0
4  Thurs     Home     2.0
5    Fri     Home     2.0
6    Mon     Home     1.0
7    Sat     Home     2.0
8    Sun     Home     3.0
9   Tues     Away     NaN
```

If want integer column:

```
df['Assign'] = np.where(mask, df['Day'].map(d), 0)
print (df)
     Day Location  Assign
0    Mon     Home       1
1   Tues     Home       1
2    Mon     Away       0
3    Wed     Home       1
4  Thurs     Home       2
5    Fri     Home       2
6    Mon     Home       1
7    Sat     Home       2
8    Sun     Home       3
9   Tues     Away       0
```

And if not problem with mixed numeric with empty strings:

```
df['Assign'] = np.where(mask, df['Day'].map(d), '')
print (df)
     Day Location Assign
0    Mon     Home      1
1   Tues     Home      1
2    Mon     Away       
3    Wed     Home      1
4  Thurs     Home      2
5    Fri     Home      2
6    Mon     Home      1
7    Sat     Home      2
8    Sun     Home      3
9   Tues     Away
```

Comment: Thanks mate. What if I wanted a string in the `Assign` instead of numbers?

Comment: @Maxibon - You are welcome! Then use `d = dict(zip(df1['Day'], np.arange(len(df1)) // 3 + 1).astype(str))`

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks @jezrael